# Powerbuilder: ImportFile of UTF-8 (Converting UTF-8 to ANSI)

Tags: utf-8, powerbuilder, datawindow

My Powerbuilder version is 6.5, cannot use a higher version as this is what I am supporting.

My problem is, when I am doing dw_1.ImportFile(file) the first row and first column has a funny string like this:

```
ï»¿
```

Which I dont understand until I tried opening the file and saving it to a new text file and trying to import that new file.which worked flawlessly without the funny string.

My conclusion is that this is happening because the file is UTF-8 (as shown in NOTEPAD++) and the new file is Ansi. The file I am trying to import is automatically given by a 3rd party and my users dont want the extra job of doing this.

How do I force convert this files to ANSI in powerbuilder. If there is none, I might have to do a command prompt conversion, any ideas?

Comment: Looks like a UTF-8 byte order mark, the Unicode ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE character. You can just delete those three bytes. (BTW, "ANSI" is a misnomer for a family of Microsoft-specific 8-bit encodings including Windows-1252.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: If the file contains some encoded accentuated or extended characters, just removing the utf-8 BOM (that is actually the weird string prefix) won't produce a correct result. Your right concerning the ANSI misnaming, but with PowerBuilder `encodingAnsi!` is the constant for native 1252 encoded files (beside `encodingUtf8!`, `encodingutf16le` and `encodingUtf16be`)

Comment: Sorry, if not ANSI, what should it be called. Anyhow I will try and get back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The weird `ï»¿` characters are the (optional) utf-8 BOM that tells editors that the file is utf-8 encoded (as it can be difficult to know it unless we encounter an escaped character above code 127). You cannot just rid it off because if your file contains any character above 127 (accents or any special char), you will still have garbage in your displayed data (for example: `é` -> `Ã©`, `€` -> `â‚¬`, ...) where special characters will become from 2 to 4 garbage chars.

I recently needed to convert some utf-8 encoded string to "ansi" windows 1252 encoding. With version of PB10+, a reencoding between utf-8 and ansi is as simple as

```
b = blob(s, encodingutf8!)
s2 = string(b, encodingansi!)
```

But `string()` and `blob()` do not support encoding specification before the release 10 of PB.

What you can do is to read the file yourself, skip the BOM, ask Windows to convert the string encoding via `MultiByteToWideChar()` + `WideCharToMultiByte()` and load the converted string in the DW with `ImportString()`.

Proof of concept to get the file contents (with this reading method, the file cannot be bigger than 2GB):

```
string ls_path, ls_file, ls_chunk, ls_ansi
ls_path = sle_path.text
int li_file
if not fileexists(ls_path) then return

li_file = FileOpen(ls_path, streammode!)
if li_file > 0 then
    FileSeek(li_file, 3, FromBeginning!) //skip the utf-8 BOM

    //read the file by blocks, FileRead is limited to 32kB
    do while FileRead(li_file, ls_chunk) > 0
        ls_file += ls_chunk //concatenate in loop works but is not so performant
    loop

    FileClose(li_file)

    ls_ansi = utf8_to_ansi(ls_file)
    dw_tab.importstring( text!, ls_ansi)
end if
```

`utf8_to_ansi()` is a globlal function, it was written for PB9, but it should work the same with PB6.5:

```
global type utf8_to_ansi from function_object
end type

type prototypes
function ulong MultiByteToWideChar(ulong CodePage, ulong dwflags, ref string lpmultibytestr, ulong cchmultibyte, ref blob lpwidecharstr, ulong cchwidechar) library "kernel32.dll"
function ulong WideCharToMultiByte(ulong CodePage, ulong dwFlags, ref blob lpWideCharStr, ulong cchWideChar, ref string lpMultiByteStr, ulong cbMultiByte, ref string lpUsedDefaultChar, ref boolean lpUsedDefaultChar) library "kernel32.dll"
end prototypes

forward prototypes
global function string utf8_to_ansi (string as_utf8)
end prototypes

global function string utf8_to_ansi (string as_utf8);

//convert utf-8 -> ansi
//use a wide-char native string as pivot

constant ulong CP_ACP = 0
constant ulong CP_UTF8 = 65001

string ls_wide, ls_ansi, ls_null
blob lbl_wide
ulong ul_len
boolean lb_flag

setnull(ls_null)
lb_flag = false

//get utf-8 string length converted as wide-char
setnull(lbl_wide)
ul_len = multibytetowidechar(CP_UTF8, 0, as_utf8, -1, lbl_wide, 0)
//allocate buffer to let windows write into
ls_wide = space(ul_len * 2)
lbl_wide = blob(ls_wide)
//convert utf-8 -> wide char
ul_len = multibytetowidechar(CP_UTF8, 0, as_utf8, -1, lbl_wide, ul_len)
//get the final ansi string length
setnull(ls_ansi)
ul_len = widechartomultibyte(CP_ACP, 0, lbl_wide, -1, ls_ansi, 0, ls_null, lb_flag)
//allocate buffer to let windows write into
ls_ansi = space(ul_len)
//convert wide-char -> ansi
ul_len = widechartomultibyte(CP_ACP, 0, lbl_wide, -1, ls_ansi, ul_len, ls_null, lb_flag)

return ls_ansi
end function
```

Comment: I am importing 35000+ rows (TAB DELIMITED COLUMNS) to the dw. can I still use the ImportString in this case?

Comment: Actually I am storing these Rows to a temp table in SQL. Then did a LOOP to parse each row, read, and insert the proper data to the main table. If I could determine these characters, can I just remove them and insert the proper value? Do we have a known fixed possible chars/string that I should look into? I was going to do a regex instead.

Comment: Hi Seki, This works flawlessly, 1 thing.. I used ImportString(ls_file) only for 6.5. Adding "text!" would result to syntax error on my version. Thank you very much for this.

Comment: Hi Again seki, Another thing. How would I know if the file is not UTF, on my scenario. there are several third parties sending us TAB Delimited Files, not all are UTF-8. Now when I tried using the ANSI Encoding, It seems it removed characters from the first row.

Comment: NVM, thanks, I read the file and check if the first string is in range of ASCII ASC(string) > 0 AND ASC(string) < 126. TY again.

Comment: If you look at the first bytes of an utf-16  you will see 0xFF 0xFE or 0xFE 0xFF (utf16-le / utf16-be) for utf-8 if will be 0xEF 0xBB 0xBF unfortunately it is not mandatory so you cannot be 100% sure it not utf-8 when itis not present. And no, you cannot safely filter escaped characters with regex.

Comment: Hi Seki, actually I had a problem. Out of 35k rows, only the first 200 are being imported. Is this because I am reading the file into string?

Comment: @Sid: I forgot that `FileRead()` can only read up to 32kB at once. Your 200 lines must size 32kB. I have updated my sample code to read a file bigger than 32kB by looping until the end and concatenate the blocks. The limit is now about 2GB (the max length of a string variable)