# Powerbuilder: Converting UTF-8 to UTF-8 without bom

Tags: utf-8, powerbuilder

Good Night, I need to convert a text file from UTF-8 to UTF-8 without bom in powerbuilder
I get to identify and supposed to remove the bom from the text but when I re-record it continues with the bom, please help

```
                integer li_fnum
                long ll_bytes
                
                li_fnum = FileOpen(ls_archivo, StreamMode!)
                ll_bytes = FileReadEx(li_fnum, lblb_file_contents)

                if len(lblb_file_contents) >= 3 then
                        GetByte(lblb_file_contents, 1, lbt_1)
                        GetByte(lblb_file_contents, 2, lbt_2)
                        GetByte(lblb_file_contents, 3, lbt_3)
                    if lbt_1 = 239 and lbt_2 = 187 and lbt_3 = 191 then // BOM for UTF8 = EF    BB BF
                        // BOM is found - remove it from the blob
                        lblb_file_contents = BlobMid(lblb_file_contents, 4, len(lblb_file_contents) - 3)
                        // Check the truncated contents once again
                        if len(lblb_file_contents) = 0 then
                        MessageBox("Error", "There's no data in the file!", StopSign!)
                        return
                        end if
                    end if
                end if
```

Comment: you can remove the length parameter, without it, it will return the blob with offset 4 e.g.  `BlobMid(lbl_file_contents, 4)`  btw maybe this may help > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336948/powerbuilder-importfile-of-utf-8-converting-utf-8-to-ansi

Comment: after many attempts what worked was to remove the encoding, still thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You convert the data type `text` to `blob` with encoding UTF-8 and write the file down:

```
i=FileWriteEx(f, blob(text,EncodingUTF8!) )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Create function remove_utf8_bom (String as_file)

 Integer    li_fnum    
 Long       ll_bytes    
 String     ls_file_contents    
 Blob       lblb_file_contents     
 Byte       lbt_1, lbt_2, lbt_3
 
 li_fnum = FileOpen(as_file, StreamMode!)

 ll_bytes = FileReadEx(li_fnum, lblb_file_contents)

 FileClose(li_fnum)

 if len(lblb_file_contents) >= 3 then

            GetByte(lblb_file_contents, 1, lbt_1)    
            GetByte(lblb_file_contents, 2, lbt_2)    
            GetByte(lblb_file_contents, 3, lbt_3)

      if lbt_1 = 239 and lbt_2 = 187 and lbt_3 = 191 then // BOM for UTF8 = EF    BB BF
            // BOM is found - remove it from the blob
            lblb_file_contents = BlobMid(lblb_file_contents, 4, len(lblb_file_contents) - 3)

            // Check the truncated contents once again
            if len(lblb_file_contents) = 0 then    
                //MessageBox("Error", "There's no data in the file!", StopSign!)
                return    
            end if

      end if

 end if
 
 li_fnum = FileOpen(as_file, StreamMode!, Write!, Shared!, Replace!)    
 FileWriteEx(li_fnum, blob(string(lblb_file_contents, EncodingUTF8!),EncodingUTF8!) )    
 FileClose(li_fnum)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.